# Create a scaled thumbnail of image and echoing out results in organized fashion 3 columns, unlimited rows, one tile in each column for each row

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

So far this script works pretty well. However its not quite what I'm looking for. I have it echoing out a form, and for each image it finds, it echoes out a div and other goodness related to the image. Currently it echoes all found images in a nice long single column, and the scaled images are not very proportionate, (they look warped).

However here is what I would like, and I'm not 100% how to go about it. Instead of one long single column, I  would like to have three or four `<div class=\"imageTile\">\n";` in each row until the script runs out of images. The tiles should be aligned in nice little columns.

Second I have not quite figured out how to scale the images it finds to where they DO NOT look warped. (Basically trying to make a thumbnail of the image, so that when the image is clicked, the original image will eventually appear).

```
      <?php
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            // if no project was sent, display some error message
            if(!isset($_GET['urlName'])) { die('No project has been chosen'); }
            // cast the project to integer (just a little bit of basic security)
            $urlname = (string) $_GET['urlName'];
            $path = $urlname;
            if (strpos($path, '../') !== false || strpos($path, "..\\") !== false || strpos($path, '/..') !== false || strpos($path, '\..') !== false)
                    {
                    // Strange things happening. 403 Forbidden
                    http_response_code(403);
                    } else {
            $dir = "uploads/$path";
            function ListFiles($dir) {
                if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                    $files = Array();
                    $inner_files = Array();
                    while($file = readdir($dh)) {
                        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                            if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                                $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                                if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files);
                            } else if (strstr($file, ".gif") || strstr($file, ".png") || strstr($file, ".jpg")) {
                                array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($dh);
                    return $files;
                }
            }

echo "<form onsubmit=\"\">\n";           
            foreach (ListFiles("uploads/$path") as $key=>$file){
             $directory_file = $directory . $file;
                    $info = getImageSize($file);
             echo " <div class=\"imageTile\">\n";
             echo "   <img src=\"$directory_file\" width=\"110px\" height=\"120px\"><br>\n";
             echo "   <input class=\"data\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"imageFilename\" value=\"$file\">\n";
             echo "   <input class=\"data\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"imageGalleryID\" value=\"$path\">\n";
             echo "   <label for=\"$file\">Keep</label>\n";
             echo "   <input class=\"checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\">\n";
             echo " </div>\n";
            }
             echo " <div id=\"submit_buttons\">\n";
             echo "  <button type=\"reset\">Reset</button>\n";
             echo "  <input class=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" onclick=\"return false\" value=\"Submit\">\n";
             echo " </div>\n";
             echo "</form>\n";
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your CSS looks like, but you can align the divs inline with each other and (provided they have a fixed width and height) they will align in columns. Try adding `float:left;` in your `imageTile` selector in your CSS.

As for your second question, if you set `max-height` or `max-width` in your CSS, most modern browsers will maintain the aspect ratio of the image and resize it according to the max width or max height.

Change this line:

```
echo "   <img src=\"$directory_file\" width=\"110px\" height=\"120px\"><br>\n";
```

to this:

```
echo "   <img src=\"$directory_file\" style=\"max-width: 120px; max-height: 110px;\" /><br>\n";
```